# Scroll slowly the parent container when data rows exceed the height

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a php file (myphpfile.php) that pulls data from a mysql table. 
I have an html file (good.html) with a Jquery load that embeds the php file in a container.

When data is bigger than the height of the wrapper, I want to start scrolling the table slowly then fade back to the top row of the table and keep looping.

I think that the height is not being calculated because the wrapper is empty before the php page is loaded. 
So, please help. How do I accomplish that.

```
  <?php 


  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "my user";
  $pass = "my pass";

  $databaseName = "somedatabase";
  $tableName = "variables";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");            //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //echo json_encode($array);



 // Begin your table outside of the array

 echo "<div class='main-container'>";
 echo "<div class='row-header'>";
 echo "<div class='data-cell cell-header'>Event Name</div><div class='data-cell cell-header'>Event Location</div><div class='data-cell cell-header'>Start Time</div><div class='data-cell cell-header'>End Time</div>";
 echo "</div>";   




 //echo "<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>";
 //echo"<th class=\"th1\"><a href=\"admin\" target=\"_blank\">TODAY'S  EVENTS</a></th><th class=\"th2\">EVENT LOCATION</th><th class=\"th3\">STARTING</th><th class=\"th4\">ENDING</th>";

 // Define your colors for the alternating rows
$color1 = "#e4dad2"; 
$color2 = "#efeae6"; 
$row_count = 0;
date("Y/m/d");
$today = date("m/d/Y");
//$today = date("F j, Y");
$date=(Date("F j, Y")); // Date 

// Perform an statndard SQL query:

$sql_events = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY event_date DESC") or die (mysql_error()); 
//$sql_events = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE event_date='" .$today."' ORDER BY event_date ASC, start_time_part ASC, start_time_hr ASC, //start_time_mn DESC") or die (mysql_error());

// We are going to use the "$row" method for this query. This is just my preference.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_events)) {
    $event_date = $row["event_date"];
    $event_title = $row["name"];
    $event_location = $row["event_location"];
    $event_start_hr = $row["start_time_hr"];
    $event_start_mn = $row["start_time_mn"];
    $event_start_ampm = $row["start_time_part"];
    $event_end_hr = $row["end_time_hr"];
    $event_end_mn = $row["end_time_mn"];
    $event_end_ampm = $row["end_time_part"];

    /* Now we do this small line which is basically going to tell
    PHP to alternate the colors between the two colors we defined above. */
    $row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;

    // Echo your table row and table data that you want to be looped over and over here.
    echo "<div class='data-row'>";
    echo "<div class='data-cell cell1'>$event_title</div>";
    echo "<div class='data-cell cell2'>$event_location</div>";
    echo "<div class='data-cell cell3'>$event_start_hr : $event_start_mn  $event_start_ampm</div>";
    echo "<div class='data-cell cell4'>$event_end_hr : $event_end_mn $event_end_ampm</div>";
    echo "</div>";


   // echo "<tr>";

//  echo"<td class=\"td1\" bgcolor=$row_color><b>$event_title</b></td>";
//  echo"<td class=\"td2\" bgcolor=$row_color><b>$event_location</b></td>";
//    echo"<td class=\"td3\" bgcolor=$row_color><b>$event_start_hr : $event_start_mn  $event_start_ampm</b></td>";
//  echo"<td class=\"td4\" bgcolor=$row_color><b>$event_end_hr : $event_end_mn $event_end_ampm</b></td>";//
//    echo "</tr>";

    // Add 1 to the row count
    $row_count++;
}
// Close out your table.
//echo "</table>";

echo "</div>";
// close connection
mysql_close(); 


?>
```

and my Html page with the Jquery is this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">body {
background-color:#f9f9f9;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:15px;
}

.wrapper {
max-width:1200px;
margin:1em auto;
background-color:#fff;
border:1px solid #ddd;
box-shadow:0px 0px 6px #eee;
}

#load_updates {
 position:relative;
 width:800px;
 height:400px;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:4em 0 4em 2em;

}

.main-container {
 display:table;
 min-height:300px;
 width:100%;
}

.row-header {
 font-weight:700;
 background-color:#444;
 color:#f9f9f9;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
 font-size:1.3em;
 display:table-row; 
 float:none;
 min-height:1.8em;
 padding:.2em 0;
 width:100%;
}


.data-row {
 display:table-row;
 float:none;
 border-bottom:1px dotted #ddd;
 min-height:1.8em;
 padding:.2em 0;
 width:100%;
}

.data-row {
font-size:1.3em;
}


.data-row:nth-child(even) {
background-color:#efefef;}

}

.data-row:nth-child(odd) {
background-color:#f4f4f4;}

.data-row:after {
 display:table;
 float:none;
 width:100%;
 height:0;}

.data-cell {
 display:table-cell;
 float:left;
 text-align:left;
 padding:.5em .6em;
 width:22.5%;
}

#tb {
height:auto;}

#tb table {
min-height:300px;
}


.cell-header {
}

.ts {border:1px solid #ddd;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$("#tb").load("myphpfile.php").fadeIn("slow");
}, 1800); // refresh every 1800 milliseconds

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="load_updates">
<div class="ts" id="tb"></div>
</div>

<div id="load_heights"></div>
<script>


<div id="result"> </div>
<script>

</script></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.fn.myFunction = function() {


            var boxhigh = jQuery("#load_updates").height();
            var tbhigh = jQuery("#tb").height();
            var differencehigh = tbhigh - boxhigh;

            if (differencehigh > 0) {
                $(this).css("color", "red");
                $(this).animate({ "top": "-=160" }, 10000 );

          $("#load_heights")( "innerHeight:" );;    
        return true;

            }


};

$("#tb").myFunction();
</script><script>

$.get( "myphpfile.php", function( data ) {
$( "#result" ).html(data);

});

</script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: nasty approach.. why do you want to load php through ajax onto html?

Comment: wrap your JS inside `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: I have a CMS that has other items. In one of those windows, I have to get that event table to display. But because the CMS has a limited window for the table, I need to make sure the table scrolls when there are more event rows that what that windows can show. Hope this justifies the nasty approach.